# script inside scriptlet - bad practice how to avoid

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, scriptlet

i am working on a legacy project where i have seen below piece of code.
I know it is a bad practice to use script inside scriptlet.
Regarding this , i have few confusion in mind.

1. what i believe is scriptlet is executed before page loads, so if below if condition is true then ShowBookReference() function call is a part of an Html page, but my question is when page is rendered should this function call happens or not ?

```html
 <% if (refLinkTerm != null) { %>
          <script Language="javascript">
          ShowBookReference('<%=sub2ndNavMenu%>', '<%=refLinkTerm%>', <%=String.valueOf(searchType)%>, <%=String.valueOf(codeType)%>)
          </script>
    <%}%>
```

2. How to avoid this kind of practice ?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Use an MVC framework such as Spring MVC. In these frameworks, you fill in a Java object (or map of objects) with the values for the page to display, and then the page just fills in placeholders with those values.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of JSP, Its usual to use `scriptlets` to assign value to JS.

But as you've mentioned that it runs before the page load, so it's good to run the function on window.onload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
          ShowBookReference('<%=sub2ndNavMenu%>', '<%=refLinkTerm%>', <%=String.valueOf(searchType)%>, <%=String.valueOf(codeType)%>)
       }
</script>
```

In case you're referring some DOM elements inside `ShowBookReference` function, it may not be available so run it on page load.

Else you can use UI frameworks like JSF which provides you tags to bind java values to UI easily.

Comment: if some method xyz()is already mentioned on body onload() , does your approach calls both xyz() and ShowBookReference() ?

Comment: No it won't. In that case you must bind event using `addEventListener` it will trigger all the event handlers. In terms of property based event handlers, they get overridden by later event handlers. So use attachEvent/addEventListener for that purpose

Comment: Don't use JSF. It has a number of fatal flaws in its core architecture and has been superseded by better approaches.